Is the CheckSignature method of x509.Certificate safe to be called from multiple go routines?
I am trying to understand if the CheckSignature function from crypto/x509 is safe to be called from multiple go routines at the same time? I tried to look for any comments but couldn't find anything.
This is the function definition I am talking about
func (c *x509.Certificate) CheckSignature(algo x509.SignatureAlgorithm, signed []byte, signature []byte) error

Link to the line of code in Github

The CheckSignatureFrom function in the crypto/x509 package is designed to verify that the signature on a RevocationList (CRL) is valid and was created by the issuer's certificate.
This function is safe to call from multiple goroutines at the same time. The reason for this is that CheckSignatureFrom does not modify any shared state or data. Instead, it only reads from the RevocationList and Certificate structures that are passed to it.

Yes it is safe.
Actually there is no shared resource for any race condition to get happened.
